# How do I access the current user with polymerfire in a child element?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I created a user and logged in, using `<firebase-auth>` (with code snippet below) in the main element, but I can only retrieve the user's information in that main element (and not a child element).

```
    <firebase-auth
        id="auth"
        app-name="Carecollector"
        provider="google"
        signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
        user="{{user}}">
    </firebase-auth>
```

How do I retrieve information about the current user in a child element?
Should I create a `<firebase-auth>` element inside every other element that needs the current user information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as others have said, drop a <**firebase-auth**> in the child element you want to retrieve the user's information. Also add a property to the child element and use Polymer's data binding system to expose the property to your element. Suppose you want to access user data in a child element,

**HTML**:

drop <**firebase-auth**> in your element like this;

```
<firebase-auth user="{{currentuser}}"></firebase-auth>
```

**SCRIPT**:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'your-element-name',
      properties:{
          currentuser: Object
    });
</script>
```

Then you can get, for example, the user's **displayName** like this:

```
<div>[[currentuser.displayName]]</div>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop another firebase-auth anywhere you need to access the current user

Comment: i just dropped another firebase-auth in another element but the user property has a null value when i try to access it. i'm currently using iron-mete as a workarround to this

Comment: that definitely should work.  you shouldn't have to use iron-meta.  something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Tyler says "Just drop another firebase-auth anywhere you need to access the current user" and I voted it down because it just wasn't true!

I had proved that you DON'T have access to the user, through frequent bouts of testing and debugging to figure this one out. Undefined, null, anything but a user there!

Except he was right... and you'd never know it unless you set an observer on that property or something similar. Because the user value is populated when it is populated, and for a javascript newbie like me I never thought about that, and kept trying to access this before it was populated. Sometimes it takes a second or two.